# Free and easiest DB system that can sustain hundreds of Gigabytes with good performance?

Tags: database

I'm looking that is easy and well documented and free. Does this exist ? Not in memory database all on disk and not distributed.

Comment: Do you know what you're planning to use it for? Different solutions can be better at different types of workload. For example, do you need to be able to search through lots of text quickly?

Comment: You may also want to constraint your question a bit, OS? SQL vs NoSQL support for some language? Etc.

Comment: There is no free "one-size-fits-all" DB (IMHO not even a commercial one). So without giving us more information about your goals, don't expect to get a useful answer.

Comment: @thirdot store and query stock data every 100 milliseconds for thousands of symbols :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is free, easy, can sustain very large amount of data, has fantastic performance metrics, and is fairly well documented.  Of course, these listed requirements aren't very specific...

Comment: Thanks wait for others if any :)